# LINQ to get distinct column value with count of a string

Tags: linq, c#-4.0

I have below data in datatable -

```
Col1       Col2
-----------------------
Pramod  |   In
Pramod  |   In
Pramod  |   Out
Pramod  |   In
Pramod  |   In
Pramod  |   Out
Pankaj  |   In
Pankaj  |   In
Pankaj  |   Out
Abhi    |   In
Abhi    |   In
Abhi    |   Out
```

I want below output using LINQ,

```
Col1    | In |  Out
------------------
Pramod  | 4  |  2
Pankaj  | 2  |  1
Abhi    | 2  |  1
```

Please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Group rows by value of `Col1` and then calculate number of `In` and `Out` values in each group:

```
from r in table.AsEnumerable()
group r by r.Field<string>("Col1") into g
select new {
    Col1 = g.Key,
    In = g.Count(r => r.Field<string>("Col2") == "In"),
    Out = g.Count(r => r.Field<string>("Col2") == "Out")
}
```

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy.. thank you so much, i found LINQ very useful for complex queries, As I am new for LINQ, can you suggest some books to learn LINQ

Comment: @user3240893 I suggest you to view [pluralsight](http://www.pluralsight.com/training) LINQ tutorials. They are very informative